# Why is my output formatted, i.e. '\n' automatically in fgets?

Tags: c, fgets

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
FILE* fp;
int i;
fp=fopen("newfile","r");
if(fp==NULL)
{
   printf("hhaha");
   return 0;
}
char str[20];
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    fgets(str,20,fp);
    printf("%s",str);
} 
return 0;
}
```

Now if my newfile has text

> my name
>   is xyz

then how come when i print the two lines are printed in two newlines?
where does the newline character come from?

Comment: @cwallenpoole are you sure you didn't change the whole point of the question with that edit?  If there was an empty line in his test file, then when printf fired wouldn't it have printed two carriage returns on the screen?

Comment: @DJQuimby  there was no empty lines.  there were just two text lines separated by carriage return.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  I misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets` sets the pointer to a `char *` representing the line of the file including the `\n` at the end of the line. (As is the case with most strings, it will also be `'\0'` terminated)

A file with this:

> This
> is
> my
> file

Will have this from `fgets`:

`This\n\0`,`is\n\0`,`my\n\0`,`file\n\0`<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>The final value may not be include `\n`. That will depend on whether it is a `\n` terminated file.

Comment: i.e. my str on first iteration gives me "my name\n"?

Comment: or it contains "my name\0\n"   .. what actually my str is?

Comment: Yeah, you are reading the characters to the end of the line, including the `\n`. So the string is actually `[m][y][ ][n][a][m][e][\n][\0]`

Comment: @Robert Martin  isnt it a bad thing for me.. what if i wanted to check if my str was equal to "my name"? it never will return me true?
then why shall i use fgets at all?

Comment: @Karan You have to account for this. You can do a strlen() to check if the last char is a \n and if it is, set it to be \0 first. Or you could do something fancy like `int strcmpfancy(char *a, char *b){while ((*a)&&(*a == *b)){a++; b++} return (!(*a) && (!(*b) || *b=='\n');}   **Untested**

Answer (score 1):

from `man fgets`

> gets()  reads  a  line  from stdin into the buffer pointed to
>    by s until either a terminating newline or EOF, which it replaces with
>   '\0'.  No check for buffer overrun is performed
>          (see BUGS below).
>
> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from
>   stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops
>   after an EOF or a newline.  **If a newline is read,
>          it is stored into the buffer**.  A '\0' is stored after the last
>   character in the buffer.

and thus `fgets` behaviour is different from what you might expect

Answer (score 0):

From the linux man page for fgets():

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from
>   stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops 
>   after an EOF or a newline.  **If a newline  is read,  it  is stored into 
>   the buffer.** A '\0' is stored after the last character in thebuffer.

Comment: isnt it a bad thing for me.. what if i wanted to check if my str was equal to "my name"? it never will return me true?
then why shall i use fgets at all?

Comment: @Karan: Use `strchr()` to locate a newline within the string OR simply use `strlen()` and if the last character is a newline, set it a '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` includes the newline when reading into the string - that's how `fgets()` is defined to work. From the standard:

> No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file.